# ORACLE apex - looping through checkbox items using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a checkbox on my page `P3_Checkbox1` that is populated from the database. How can I loop through all the checked values of my checkbox in PL/SQL code?

I assume that `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01` is used only by sql generated checkboxes and I cannot use it for regular checbox as it would not populate G_Fxx array.

Comment: What kind of a region is it?

Comment: just a static region with a select list and a checkbox

Comment: So - only one checkbox item on the page (P3_CHECKBOX1)? If so, I don't quite understand what would you loop through. You know - loop means "doing something several times" (although you can loop only once, but that doesn't make much sense). I just don't understand the question ... If possible, post a screenshot of that page so that we could see what you have.

Comment: there is one checkbox item but it has several values - sort of like checkbox list

Comment: so if I grab the P3_Checkbox1 page item from my PL/SQL, I will get an array and I will need to loop through it

Comment: OK, I think I got it; I posted an answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now what you're saying.

For example, suppose that the `P3_CHECKBOX1` checkbox item allows 3 values (display/return):

- Absent: -1
- Unknown: 0
- Here: 1

I created a button (which will just `SUBMIT` the page) and two text items which will display checked values: `P3_CHECKED_VALUES` and `P3_CHECKED_VALUES_2`.

Then I created a **process** which fires when the button is pressed. The process looks like this (read the comments as well, please):

```
begin
  -- This is trivial; checked (selected) values are separated by a colon sign, 
  -- just like in a Shuttle item
  :P3_CHECKED_VALUES := :P3_CHECKBOX1;
  
  -- This is what you might be looking for; it uses the APEX_STRING.SPLIT function
  -- which splits selected values (the result is ROWS, not a column), and these
  -- values can then be used in a join or anywhere else, as if it was result of a
  -- subquery. The TABLE function is used as well.
  -- LISTAGG is used just to return a single value so that I wouldn't have to worry
  -- about TOO-MANY-ROWS error.
  with 
  description (code, descr) as
    (select -1, 'Absent'  from dual union all
     select 0 , 'Unknown' from dual union all
     select 1 , 'Here'    from dual),
  desc_join as
    (select d.descr
     from description d join (select * from table(apex_string.split(:P3_CHECKED_VALUES, ':'))) s
     on d.code = s.column_value
    )
  select listagg(j.descr, ' / ') within group (order by null) 
    into :P3_CHECKED_VALUES_2
  from desc_join j;
end;
```

Suppose that the Absent and Unknown values have been checked. The result of that PL/SQL process is:

```
P3_CHECKED_VALUES   = -1:0
P3_CHECKED_VALUES_2 = Absent / Unknown
```

You can rewrite it as you want; this is just one example.

Keywords:

- `APEX_STRING.SPLIT`
- `TABLE` function

### Edit: loop through selected values

Looping through those values isn't difficult; you'd do it as follows (see the cursor `FOR` loop):

```
declare
  l_dummy number;
begin
  for cur_r in (select * From table(apex_string.split(:P3_CHECKED_VALUES, ':'))) 
  loop
    select max(1)
      into l_dummy
      from some_table where some_column = cur_r.column_value;
      
    if l_dummy is null then
       -- checked value does not exist
       insert into some_table (some_column, ...) valued (cur_r.column_value, ...);
    else
       -- checked value exists
       delete from some_table where ...
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

However, I'm not sure what you meant by saying that a "particular combination is in the database". Does it mean that you are storing colon-separated values into a column in that table? If so, the above code won't work either because you'd compare, for example

- `-1` to `0:-1` and then
- `0` to `0:-1`

which won't be true (except in the simplest cases, when checked and stored values have only one value).

Although Apex' "multiple choices" look nice, they can become a nightmare when you have to actually *do* something with them (like in your case).

Maybe you should first *sort* checkbox values, sort database values, and then compare those two strings.

It means that `LISTAGG` might once again become handy, such as

```
listagg(j.descr, ' / ') within group (order by j.descr)
```

Database values could be sorted this way:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1:0' from dual union all
  3     select '1:-1:0' from dual
  4    ),
  5  inter as
  6    (select col,
  7            regexp_substr(col, '[^:]+', 1, column_value) token
  8     from test,
  9          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ':') + 1
 11                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12    )
 13  select
 14    col source_value,
 15    listagg(token, ':') within group (order by token) sorted_value
 16  from inter
 17  group by col;

SOURCE SORTED_VALUE
------ --------------------
1:-1:0 -1:0:1
1:0    0:1

SQL>
```

Once you have them both sorted, you can compare them and either `INSERT` or `DELETE` a row.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. I need some way to loop through those comma-separated values. What I plan to do within the loop is check if a particular combination is already in the database, if it is not, I want to insert it. And if unchecked combination is in the database - delete it

Comment: I've edited my message & added some more info. Have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you! I mean that I have a database table that stores two integer values - one comes from select list, and another - from checkbox. For example if selected value of select list is 101, and checkbox values are 1,2,3,4, then I need to check that database table for combinations 101 and 1, 101 and 2 etc...

Comment: You're welcome. OK then, I suppose that you'll be able to use that cursor FOR loop I posted as the first code in the edited part of the message. Good luck!

Comment: Is creating a dummy-table from the string still the best way to select rows  matching the checkbox values? Basically I want to replace "WHERE id IN (1,2)" with "WHERE id IN <checked checkboxes>"

Comment: @Samuel, you have to - somehow - split those values into rows. It is up to you to decide how to do it.